# Count unique values if criteria is met

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Excel-Spreadsheet:**

```
            A              B           C         D         E
    1   Products         Sales       Count:      1
    2   Product_A         500       
    3   Product_A         400       
    4   Product_A           
    5   Product_B         200       
    6   Product_B           
    7   Product_C           
    8   Product_C           
    9   Product_C   
   10
   11
```

In the above Excel spreadsheet I have list of `products` and their `sales`. 
As you can see the `products` can appear multiple times in the list and not each entry does have a `sale` which causes `empty cells` in `Column B`.

Now, I want to count the **unqiue** `products` that do not have a sale at all. 
In the above case this would be only `Product_C` since the other `products` do have at least one sale in `Column B`. 
Therefore, the expected result in `Cell D1` is `1`.

So far I got to this formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B9,"<>"&"")
```

However, it counts all the `""` in `Column B` without checking if a `product` has a non-emtpy entry somewhere else in the list.

Do you have any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: Add a criterion to the countifs() function that defines each product individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `D1`, array formula (confirmed by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter) :

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(0+(COUNTIFS(A2:A9,A2:A9,B2:B9,"<>")=0),MATCH(A2:A9,A2:A9,0)),ROW(A2:A9)-ROW(A1))>0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you would have Excel O365, you could try:

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A9,COUNTIFS(A2:A9,A2:A9,B2:B9,">0")=0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Unique Zero Count

If you're not allergic to VBA here's a flexible UDF. Rows `1-3` demonstrate that it is enough to select any cell as the 2nd argument as long it is in the `Sales` column. Rows `4-5` show that the same is not allowed for the `Products` column. If the 3rd argument is set to `TRUE`, rows `6-8` show that it is allowed to specify the `Products` column using only a cell as long as it is the first to be checked. Row `8` shows how `Product_D` is not counted. Row `9` shows the behavior when out of bounds (`0`).

[image]

```vb
Option Explicit

Function Unique0Count(UniqueRange As Range, ValueRange As Range, _
  Optional calculateLastCell As Boolean = False) As Long

    Dim dict As Object      ' Dictionary Object
    Dim Key As Variant      ' Dictionary Key (For Each Control Variable)
    Dim rng As Range        ' Unique Range, Unique Last Cell Range,
                            ' Value Range
    Dim Unique As Variant   ' Unique Array
    Dim Value As Variant    ' Value Array
    Dim i As Long           ' Unique/Value Array Elements (Rows) Counter

    ' Write values from Unique Range to Unique Array.
    If Not calculateLastCell Then
        Set rng = UniqueRange.Columns(1)
    Else
        Set rng = Columns(UniqueRange.Column).Find(What:="*", _
          LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
        If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Function ' No data in column.
        If rng.Row < UniqueRange.Row Then Exit Function
        Set rng = Range(UniqueRange.Cells(1), rng)
    End If
    Unique = rng
    ' Write values from Value Range to Value Array.
    Set rng = Cells(rng.Row, ValueRange.Column).Resize(rng.Rows.Count)
    Value = rng

    ' Create a reference to the Dictionary Object(Late Binding).
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    ' Loop through elements (rows) of Unique Array.
    For i = 1 To UBound(Unique)
        ' Check if value in current row of Source Array is NOT "".
        If Unique(i, 1) <> "" Then
            ' Write values of Unque Array to the Key of the Dictionary
            ' and sum the corresponding values of Value Array for each
            ' unique element to the Dictionary.
            dict(Unique(i, 1)) = dict(Unique(i, 1)) + Value(i, 1)
        End If
    Next

    ' Calculate the number of items containing value 0.
    For Each Key In dict.keys
        If dict(Key) = 0 Then Unique0Count = Unique0Count + 1
    Next Key

End Function
```